# How can I get effective file permissions?

Tags: python, c, windows, file-permissions

I'm trying to get file **effective permissions**. What is the best way to do that?

I'm trying to use `win32security` but `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(trustee)` function needs the `PyTRUSTEE` parameter. And I don't know how to set it correctly.

As a result, I need to get  the same permissions as with  Get-EffectiveAccess calling in PowerShell.

We were tried to use `Authz.h` but in that case we got the Audit failure in Windows Event Viewer.

We also tried to use `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` from `Aclapi.h` but it can become a reason of server hangup in case when we have a lot of files.

**python:**

```
dacl = win32security.GetNamedSecurityInfo( FILENAME,
 win32security.SE_FILE_OBJECT,
 win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION).GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
mask = dacl.GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl( ??? )
```

**Authz.h**:

```
AuthzInitializeResourceManager(AUTHZ_RM_FLAG_NO_AUDIT, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &hManager);
AuthzInitializeContextFromSid(0, psid, hManager, NULL, unusedId, NULL, &hAuthzClientContext);
AuthzFreeResourceManager(hManager);

accessRequest->DesiredAccess = MAXIMUM_ALLOWED;
accessRequest->PrincipalSelfSid = NULL;
accessRequest->ObjectTypeList = NULL;
accessRequest->ObjectTypeListLength = 0;
accessRequest->OptionalArguments = NULL;
RtlZeroMemory(Buffer, sizeof(Buffer));
accessReply->ResultListLength = 1;

accessReply->GrantedAccessMask = (PACCESS_MASK)LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(ACCESS_MASK));
accessReply->Error = (PDWORD)(Buffer + sizeof(ACCESS_MASK));

AuthzAccessCheck(0, hAuthzClient, accessRequest, NULL, psd, NULL, 0, accessReply, NULL)
```

**Aclapi.h**

```
ACCESS_MASK accessRights;
TRUSTEE trustee;

BuildTrusteeWithName(&trustee, trav->user);
retcode = GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl( acl,&trustee,&accessRights);
```

I'm need to get something like that:

FILE_READ_DATA
FILE_WRITE_DATA
FILE_APPEND_DATA
FILE_READ_EA
FILE_WRITE_EA
FILE_EXECUTE
FILE_DELETE_CHILD
FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTE
FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTE
DELETE
READ_CONTROL
WRITE_DAC
WRITE_OWNER
SYNCHRONIZE

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Are you trying to display this information to the user, or are you trying to learn whether you can actually do something to a file?  In the latter case, don't bother; just attempt the actual operation and see if it fails.

Comment: How would you do something as a different user to see if it fails. I certainly can't act as though I am a different user without having their password. I can't think of any instance where I have wanted to check effective rights for my own account because as you say I just try to do whatever I want to know if I have the rights to do.

Comment: I'm need to get full info about all file permissions (FILE_READ_DATA, FILE_WRITE_DATA, FILE_APPEND_DATA, ...) for all users.

Comment: We run this code from System account.

Comment: Why don't you use the PowerShell `*-Acl` cmdlets?

Comment: I don't think those do effective permissions do they? For instance if I have direct access rights then it would show that but if I had rights because I was a member of a group then I don't think it knows that I personally do.

Comment: @EBGreen You are right. But I'm running my code from System Account so it has enough access to permissions for all users.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I will try to use `*-Acl cmdlets` if it possible for effective permissions but using `C` or `python` will be more preferable.

Comment: Not sure why this question is tagged powershell then

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1  because I need the same result as with  `Get-EffectiveAccess`. Also as I mentioned earlier I will try to use your suggestion but maybe there's something more preferable.

Comment: Yeah, I was waiting for some powershell connection too.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 okay, maybe you're right.

Comment: PyWin32's `PyTRUSTEE` is a dict, e.g. `{'TrusteeForm': win32security.TRUSTEE_IS_NAME, 'TrusteeType': win32security.TRUSTEE_IS_USER, 'Identifier': username}`.

Comment: Consider that the containing directory implicitly provides the right to read attributes and delete if the user has read (list) or delete-child access to the directory. Also, the user may have additional access from enabled privileges and backup semantics (e.g. SeRestorePrivilege) and token groups for the logon session and type of logon. Also, for the integrity level (logon dependent), the token policy and object mandatory label filter read-up, write-up, and execute-up access.

Comment: @eryksun thanks, your suggestion helped me to get effective permissions but I get the `Audit Failure` in Windows logs. Is there any other ways to get effective permissions in python?

Comment: `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` shouldn't fail. `GetNamedSecurityInfo` might fail if you have don't have the right to read file security. It tries to open the file with backup semantics, so you should be able to get access in most cases if you have SeBackupPrivilege enabled.

Comment: The following enables backup privilege for the current process, if it's available in the token: `se_backup_value = win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(None, win32security.SE_BACKUP_NAME);` `htoken = win32security.OpenProcessToken(win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), win32security.TOKEN_QUERY | win32security.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES);` `prev_state = win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(htoken, False, [(se_backup_value, win32security.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)])`. Generally it's better if you change this to instead impersonate self and enable this privilege for just the current thread.

Answer (score 1):

I got some result using @eryksun help. Thanks.
Also I found [this useful example](https://sites.google.com/site/hvanbelle/programming/python/python---win32security/python---win32security---list-permissions).

```
def print_permissions(mask):
print("PERMISSION:",
      1 if bool(mask & 0x00000001) else 0,
      1 if bool(mask & 0x00000002) else 0,
      1 if bool(mask & 0x00000004) else 0,
      1 if bool(mask & 0x00000008) else 0,
      1 if bool(mask & 0x00000010) else 0,
      1 if bool(mask & 0x00000020) else 0,
      1 if bool(mask & 0x00000040) else 0,
      1 if bool(mask & 0x00000080) else 0,
      1 if bool(mask & 0x00000100) else 0,
      1 if bool(mask & 0x00010000) else 0,
      1 if bool(mask & 0x00020000) else 0,
      1 if bool(mask & 0x00040000) else 0,
      1 if bool(mask & 0x00080000) else 0,
      1 if bool(mask & 0x00100000) else 0)

def get_permissions(dacl):
for n_ace in range(dacl.GetAceCount()):
    ace = dacl.GetAce(n_ace)
    (ace_type, ace_flags) = ace[0]
    if ace_type in CONVENTIONAL_ACES:
        mask, sid = ace[1:]
    else:
        mask, object_type, inherited_object_type, sid = ace[1:]
    name, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountSid(None, sid)
    print("\nUSER:", name)
    print_permissions(mask)

for f in files:
    try:
        dacl = win32security.GetNamedSecurityInfo(
            f,
            win32security.SE_FILE_OBJECT,
            win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION).GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
    except BaseException as ex:
        winerror, funcname, strerror = ex.args
        print("Error: ", winerror,"\n")
    else:
        get_permissions(dacl)
```

I don't use `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` because it's contained in the ace.

When I tried to create a token with Privilege Constants I also got the same `Audit Failure`(in System Account case). So I didn't found any result that will work without `Audit Faulire` in both cases (System Account and Administrator) (except PowerShell).